# Interfaces y polimorfismo

Tags: java, poo, interface

quisiera aclarar una duda que tengo:

Tengo 2 clases personas con atributos (`private`) `nombre`, `edad`. Una clase `Nene` que hereda de `Persona`, una interface con una constante `valor1`, que genera un número aleatorio entero y un método abstracto `generAleatorio()`.

Desde la clase persona implemento la interfaz y el método:

```
generAleatorio() { return this.edad = valor1 , }
```

Si desde el `main` creo un objeto:

```
Persona p1  =  new Persona ()
system.out.println(p1.generaAleatorio)// imprime el numero que genero por pantalla
```

Pero cuando quiero hacer lo  siguiente no me lo permite

```
Persona p2 =  new Nene(): 
system.out.println(p2.generaAleatorio ) // siempre me muestra un 0 ;
```

¿Cómo implemento la interfaz a la clase `nene`?

Gracias, saludos

Comment: Coloca el código completo para poder tener más claro tu problema, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Para que la clase "Nene" herede de persona debes tener un extends
Esto es para indicarle al programa que los valores de la clase persona pasen a ser parte de la clase nene.

```
public class Nene extends Persona {
  // Atributos de la clase Nene

}
```

Si esto no soluciona el problema, comparte el codigo completo y con mucho gusto te ayudo!, saludos.